# How to make ascending order of java date

Tags: android

I am parsing one xml file and taking date from that xml and desplying it on android list view.my problem is that i want to display that date in ascending order in list view.I have an array of date, now i need to make ascending order of that all dates.can  any one help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to jeet's suggestion of a custom comparator would be to create your own object class which implements `Comparable` and then define a `compareTo` method as detailed [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10).

I prefer to implement a `compareTo`, as it allows you to use the various sorts built into other classes, rather than being restricted to only your `Comparator` class.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of date objects then sort it using [the `sort` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

And if you have array of dates in string format then create your own comparator which parses strings into date objects and compares those date objects. Then call the `sort` method passing your comparator.